# How do you unit test Javascript Promises using Jasmine.js?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, client-side, promise

What is a common, correct, or accepted way to **Unit test** functions using [Javascript Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) properly using [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/)?

**Example Promise:**

```javascript
function readFile(filename, enc) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    fs.readFile(filename, enc, function (err, res) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else fulfill(res);
    });
  });
}

function readJSON(filename) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject) {
    readFile(filename, 'utf8').done(function (res) {
      try {
        fulfill(JSON.parse(res));
      } catch (ex) {
        reject(ex);
      }
    }, reject);
  });
}
```

*The solution should contain a test for the sample code above. Thanks!*

Comment: Use mocha instead, mocha supports promises out of the box since recent versions, you simply return a promise and if it rejects it'll fail the test.

Comment: Also, the promise constructor is throw safe, you can just `fulfill(JSON.parse(res))` (which, you can't do in deferred objects).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the try catch is inside callback, not the promise constructor.

Comment: @Esailija you're absolutely right of course, readFile is itself a promise, but OP is using `.done` for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using [Jasminum](https://github.com/montagejs/jasminum). I’ve designed it for promises, using Q promises but it can use any conforming Promise constructor.

```
describe("readFile", function () {
    it("reads a file", function () {
        return readFile(__filename)
        .then(function (content) {
            expect(content).toContain("Unlikely nonce: Xebrohio!");
        });
    });
});
```